# Android: clear activity history on logout

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to do the following:
After visiting several activities, a user logs out from the app and is redirected to the login page.
The problem is, I want the user to not be able to go to the previous activities upon logout. the method finish() seems to work but it only destroys the method from where the user logged out.

Any ideas on the issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onStart()` of your activities, see if the user is logged in. If not, pop a dialog or start the login activity or something.

Comment: I think this is the only solution, so I will go for it.